# Apache can crash due to unable to wtite coredumps?

Tags: apache-2.2, server-crashes

apache coredumps are increasing by leaps and bounds, is this possible that while trying to write the core sumps and not able to do so because of no space left can crash apache server itself?

I am trying to figure out the exact reason for which apache server is crashing, but not able to do, I am thinking if above reason is responsible than I will either stop the debug mode or change the coredump locations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To determine "the exact reason for which apache server is crashing" you must examine (in order): The error log, your system's other log files, and the core dump that Apache left when it died. There's nothing we can do for you based on the information given here.

Comment: @voretaq7 thanks for the quick answer, I am doing the same, the reason I have not added the logs or more information is becase my question is "if it possible ,apache coredumps are increasing by leaps and bounds, is this possible that while trying to write the core sumps and not able to do so because of no space left can crash apache server itself? ",

Comment: Apache (or any other program) will not try to write a core file unless it's already encountered a fatal condition and is in the process of dying. You should however ensure that there is sufficient space for it to write a full core to (otherwise the core file will be useless for debugging).